# DBus: Watch when name disappears from bus

Tags: c, dbus

I am implimenting the [StatusNotifierWatcher](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/StatusNotifierItem/StatusNotifierWatcher/) service using the low-level DBus C library. The StatusNotifierWatcher specification requires that the watcher can know when "A StatusNotifierItem instance has disappeared from the bus" So that it can send the `StatusNotifierItemUnregistered` signal.

An example implimentation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dbus/dbus.h>

DBusConnection *conn = NULL;

void item_unregistered_signal(const char *name) {
    DBusMessage *signal = dbus_message_new_signal(
            "/org/freedesktop/StatusNotifierWatcher",
            "org.freedesktop.StatusNotifierWatcher",
            "StatusNotifierItemUnregistered");
    dbus_message_append_args(signal,
            DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
            DBUS_TYPE_INVALID);
    dbus_connection_send(conn, signal, NULL);
    dbus_message_unref(signal);
}

void watch_name(const char *name, void(*cb)(const char *)) {
    // Not sure how to impliment
}

dbus_bool_t register_item(DBusConnection *connection, DBusMessage *message, void *_data) {
    DBusError error;
    char *name;

    if (!dbus_message_get_args(message, &error,
                DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
                DBUS_TYPE_INVALID)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing method args: %s\n", error.message);
        return FALSE;
    }

    watch_name(name, item_unregistered_signal);
    return TRUE;
}

static void check_and_abort(DBusError *error) {
    if (dbus_error_is_set(error)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dbus_err: %s\n", error->message);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main() {
    DBusError error;
    dbus_error_init(&error);
    conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);
    check_and_abort(&error);

    dbus_bus_request_name(conn, "org.freedesktop.StatusNotifierWatcher",
            DBUS_NAME_FLAG_REPLACE_EXISTING,
            &error);
    check_and_abort(&error);

    dbus_connection_add_filter(conn, register_item, NULL, free);

    while(1) {
        dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch(conn, 1000);
    }
}
```

If I have the well-known name to a DBus service, how do I know when the name disappears from the bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured this out and I'll post an answer for any future poor souls who need to work with libdbus.

`org.freedesktop.DBus` sends the `NameOwnerChanged` signal whenever any DBus name changes. One can use this signal to track if an item has disappeared because the NewOwner argument is a null string.
This function can do that:

```
static DBusHandlerResult signal_handler(DBusConnection *connection,
        DBusMessage *message, void *_usr_data) {

    if (dbus_message_is_signal(message, "org.freedesktop.DBus",
            "NameOwnerChanged")) {
        const char *name;
        const char *old_owner;
        const char *new_owner;

        if (!dbus_message_get_args(message, NULL,
                DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
                DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &old_owner,
                DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &new_owner,
                DBUS_TYPE_INVALID)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error getting OwnerChanged args");
            return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;
        }
        if (strcmp(name, "") != 0) {
            // Name not lost, just swapped owners
            return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;
        }
        name_lost(name);
        return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED;
    }
    return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;
}
```

One also needs to add a match so that your program will be called with this signal. I added this in `main()`

```
dbus_bus_add_match(conn, 
        "type='signal',\
        sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',\
        interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',\
        member='NameOwnerChanged'",
        &error);
check_and_abort(&error);

dbus_connection_add_filter(conn, signal_handler, NULL, free);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) (recommended) instead of libdbus (discouraged), the equivalent is [`g_bus_watch_name()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-Watching-Bus-Names.html).

Comment: libdbus is not depreciated, it is just not recommended for most situations. In fact, it is probably kept in line with the dbus specification than any other library. Thank you for the addition though, it is good to clarify that higher level libraries have convinience functions for these.

Comment: Sorry, you’re right; it’s dbus-glib which is highly deprecated. libdbus is not deprecated, but its use is discouraged. sd-bus is generally accepted to be a better alternative for low-level D-Bus usage. I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: Generally accepted by whom? I have been using libdbus-1 for 2 weeks, and have found it to be the lightest DBus implementation. Additionally, libdbus-1 is the easiest to understand. sd-dbus has more dependencies, and some systems don't even have systemd.

Comment: ‘Generally accepted’ by the D-Bus maintainers. sd-bus does come as part of systemd, so it’s not an option if you can’t depend on systemd, correct. libdbus-1 does not have as much convenience API as sd-bus, its threading model is ill-defined, and it’s difficult to use correctly wrt memory management.

Comment: See https://lwn.net/Articles/649378/ for Lennart’s thoughts about why sd-bus is not separate from systemd.

Comment: As for Lennart's take...it's **WRONG**.  If it's a separate thing, it doesn't need to be a piece part of that monolithic (Please spare people the notion of it's in modules- if you can't have sd-bus separate from systemd, it's MONOLITHIC.)